# How to add viewbag parameter in a href?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I tried to add `item.DetailPageURL` which is an url to href in this view:

```
<h2>Search for @ViewBag.Keyword</h2>

@for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
var item = ViewBag.SearchedItems[i];
<div>
<h2>@item.Title</h2>
<img src="@item.SmallImage" alt="Image is missing"/>

<p>Items price:</p>
<p>@item.Price</p>
<p>@item.CurrencyCode</p>
<p><a href='@item.DetailPageURL'></a>Details</p>
<p>@item.CustomerReview</p>
</div>
<hr>
}
```

but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As You can see, the problem is in html.

```
<p><a href="@item.DetailPageURL"></a>Details</p>
```

The link is active, but it isn't appear, because "Details" is out of  tag.
Should be like this:

```
<p><a href="@item.DetailPageURL">Details</a></p>
```

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the below line. Did you noticed that you have used single quote `'`. In which case, variable substitution won't happen actually.

```
<p><a href='@item.DetailPageURL'></a>Details</p>
```

You need to use double quote `"` like

```
<p><a href="@(item.DetailPageURL)"></a>Details</p>
```

Also, I would cast the `ViewBag.SearchedItems` to it's actual type and use a `foreach` loop rather like below (assuming it's `List<string>` type)

```
foreach(var item in (List<string>)ViewBag.SearchedItems)
{
  // add to the view
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, because I tried that too, but did not working.

Comment: and (List<string>) type gives me an error in compilation.

Comment: @AleksandrVlasjuk, `List<string>` is just an example. cast it to exact type of your `ViewBag` property.

Comment: I get it. Thank You. But I need 13 results) and there is no need to give type to ViewBag - foreach works fine without (List<"type">). What about href. I tried like this "@(item.DetailPageURL)" too, but it do not make it as link.